# nil modal view controller error

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I try to follow the Apple's [recommendations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AlternateViews/Listings/PortraitViewController_m.html) to change the ViewController with device orientation change from Portrait to Landscape. When executing the code I always get the error message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target`.

I just can't figure out what the issue is. Here is the portion where the execution is terminated (part of the PortraitViewController):

```
- (void)updateLandscapeView
{

UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && self.presentedViewController == nil){
    if (!self.resultViewLandscapeViewController){
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandscapeViewController"];
        NSLog(@"LandscapeView initiated"); //this is called when device is turned
    }

        [self presentViewController:self.resultViewLandscapeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
//after the code above the execution is interrupted and the error message is thrown

}

else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && self.presentedViewController != nil){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the landscape viewcontroller is valid and not nil?

Comment: Dont u have to create a UIViewConreoller like this: UIViewController *a = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandscapeViewController"];?

Comment: Thanks Arbitur for giving the right hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually setting the viewcontroller after creating it.

```
self.resultViewLandscapeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandscapeViewController"];
```

Thanks to @Arbitur for pointing that out

Comment: What the heck! You are right! Thank you very much. I missed that.